# flutter/dart: accessing firebase user variables

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to access variables from the logged in user without reaching out to the server using the following snip ::

I was told to use the following approach to access the logged-in user variables, thats when I realized I had other lingering issue.

```
 User? _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

            //for display name
            _currentUser?.displayName;

            //for email
            _currentUser?.email;

            //for phoneNumber
            _currentUser?.phoneNumber;
            
            //for profile picture
            _currentUser?.photoURL;
```

```
final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
User? _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;    // I was told to use this one
```

if I print their values I get the following data back:

```
print('');
print('_currentUser:   ${_currentUser}');
print('');
print('currentUser:: ${currentUser}');
```

PRINT OUTPUT

```
flutter:
flutter: _currentUser:   User(displayName: null, email: jcasasmail@gmail.com, emailVerified: true, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-10-14 19:02:57.440Z, lastSignInTime: 2022-10-15 02:23:32.555Z), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: jcasasmail@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: jcasasmail@gmail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: U8EZAjrCWQRvll6CVmI6OpGZwcH3)
flutter:
flutter: currentUser:: Instance of 'AuthUser'
```

This leads me to believe that I am storing their data incorrectly to begin with...

Below is the user class, I think that maybe I dont really need this class because most of these values could be stored on the authentication piece?..... not 100% sure to be honest

```
@immutable
class CloudUser {
  final String documentId;
  final String userId;
  final String userState;
  final String userImage;
  final String userFirstName;
  final String userLastName;
  final String userCellNumber;
  final String userCity;
  final String userAreaCode;
  final String userAddress;
  final String? userEmail;

  const CloudUser({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.userId,
    required this.userState,
    required this.userImage,
    required this.userFirstName,
    required this.userLastName,
    required this.userCellNumber,
    required this.userCity,
    required this.userAreaCode,
    required this.userAddress,
    required this.userEmail,
  });

  String getFirstName() {
    return userFirstName;
  }

  CloudUser.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        userId = snapshot.data()[userIdColumn],
        userState = snapshot.data()[userStateColumn] ?? "",
        userImage = snapshot.data()[userImageColumn] ?? "",
        userFirstName = snapshot.data()[userFirstNameColumn] ?? "",
        userLastName = snapshot.data()[jobAreaCodeColumn] ?? "",
        userCellNumber = snapshot.data()[userCellNumberColumn] ?? "",
        userCity = snapshot.data()[userCityColumn] ?? "",
        userAreaCode = snapshot.data()[userAreaCodeColumn] ?? "",
        userAddress = snapshot.data()[userAddressColumn] ?? "",
        userEmail = snapshot.data()[userEmailColumn] ?? "";
}
```

Below is the AuthUser class::
I added some properties to see if I could save them, but I am getting an error so im probably doing something wrong here

```
@immutable
class AuthUser {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  // final String displayName;   // not working
  final bool isEmailVerified;
  const AuthUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.isEmailVerified,
    // required this.displayName,     // not working
  });

  factory AuthUser.fromFirebase(User user) => AuthUser(
        id: user.uid,
        email: user.email!,
        isEmailVerified: user.emailVerified,
        //   displayName: user.displayName!,       // not working
      );
}
```

When I am registering users, I use the following snip to interact with firebase::
As you can see, I tried to add some methods here but didn't work :(

```
  Future createUserAccount() async {
    if (_photo == null) return;
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await AuthService.firebase().createUser(
        email: _email.text,
        password: _password.text,
        // displayName: _userFirstName.text,   // not working
      );
      final userId = AuthService.firebase().currentUser?.id;
      final destination = 'user-profile-image/$userId';
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);
      await ref.putFile(_photo!);
      imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      _userService.createNewUser(
        userId: userId as String,
        userState: 'new',
        userImage: imageUrl as String,
        userFirstName: _userFirstName.text,
        userLastName: _userLastName.text,
        userCellNumber: _userCellphoneNumber.text,
        userCity: _userCity.text,
        userAreaCode: _userAreaCode.text,
        userAddress: _userAddress.text,
        userEmail: _email.text,
      );

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      AuthService.firebase().sendEmailVerification();
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(verifyEmailRoute);
    } on WeakPasswordAuthException {
      await showErrorDialog(
        context,
        'Weak password',
      );
    } on EmailAlreadyInUseAuthException {
      await showErrorDialog(
        context,
        'Email is already in use',
      );
    } on InvalidEmailAuthException {
      await showErrorDialog(
        context,
        'This is an invalid email address',
      );
    } on GenericAuthException {
      await showErrorDialog(
        context,
        'Failed to register',
      );
    }
  }
```

Should I change the registration form?
Any advice is greatly welcomed!

Im pretty sure I have to do the modification below, but I dont know how:::

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
    show FirebaseAuth, FirebaseAuthException;

class FirebaseAuthProvider implements AuthProvider {
  @override
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<AuthUser> createUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      final user = currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        return user;
      } else {
        throw UserNotLoggedInAuthException();
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        throw WeakPasswordAuthException();
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        throw EmailAlreadyInUseAuthException();
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
        throw InvalidEmailAuthException();
      } else {
        throw GenericAuthException();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      throw GenericAuthException();
    }
  }

  @override
  AuthUser? get currentUser {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      return AuthUser.fromFirebase(user);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }



}
```

Comment: I found this articles:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869474/how-can-i-add-the-displayname-to-the-firebase-user-flutter-dart.   I am going to try this approach to see if it werks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here's the problem, you were trying to assign a display name to a non-existent account because at that point the account is not created yet.

replace your FirebaseAuthProvider with this and try again.

```
@override
Future<AuthUser> createUser({
required String email,
required String password,
required String username,
}) async {
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  ).then((user) {
    user.user?.updateDisplayName(username);
  });
  final user = currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    return user;
  } else {
    throw UserNotLoggedInAuthException();
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    throw WeakPasswordAuthException();
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    throw EmailAlreadyInUseAuthException();
  } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
    throw InvalidEmailAuthException();
  } else {
    throw GenericAuthException();
  }
} catch (_) {
  throw GenericAuthException();
}
```

so what've done here is to register the user first before updating their displayname value.